# how to import com.ms.com.* in java application

Tags: java, visualj#, j++

Ineed to import com.ms.com.* in java application
I couldn't found any libraries for it to download.
I Have saw this link while i was searching but it couldn't help me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3wab6f3(v=vs.80).aspx!

could any one tell me if it is supported in java or not,and how to use it else where?

Comment: Please step away from that! Even Microsoft realized that J#/J++ are terrible ideas. What are you trying to accomplish? There's **definitely** a way to do it without those classes.

Answer (score 1):

eesh, j#....

1) get the sources

2) compile a JAR

3) add that JAR to your buildpath

4) you'll have it visible in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,I have used jacob library and replaced 
import com.ms.com.*; with import com.jacob.com.*;
Since the com.jacob classes are intended to be compatible with the Microsoft® com.ms classes